# Update MS ACCESS Query using Windows Form and Data Source Configuration Wizard

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I created a MS Access database with two tables, each linked to other MS Access databases; then I built a relationship for the newly created tables. After that, I created a Query where I can see the combined data for these two tables and assigned it a key.

The new Query table, when working from Access, works as expected. Changes made to the Query update the linked tables (and consequently the source tables).

Now I'm trying to make changes using a C# WinForm. On other forms I've created, this code did the trick:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myDbTableAdapter.Fill(myDbDataSet.My_Database);
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     try
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.myDbBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.myDbTableAdapter.Update(this.myDbDataSet.My_Database);
            this.myDbTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDbDataSet.My_Database);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update failed" + ex);
        }
    }
```

I tweaked the code a bit to make it work with the Query table (called Merged_Query), here is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        merged_QueryTableAdapter.Adapter.Fill(dbLinkDataSet.Merged_Query);
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.merged_QueryBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.merged_QueryTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(this.dbLinkDataSet.Merged_Query);
            this.merged_QueryTableAdapter.Adapter.Fill(this.dbLinkDataSet.Merged_Query);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update failed" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error and I cannot figure it out (I assigned a key to the query using the Dataset Designer but that didn't fix it):

[image]

Any help is appreciated.